# How to make Jquery Ajaxify plugin work with the new Jquery History plugin

Tags: ajax, browser-history

I have a question, that I am sure alot of others are wondering as well..

The jquery.ajaxify plugin uses an old history.js file, along with a history.fixed.js file that once allowed it to utilize history with most if not all browsers..it no longer works in chrome:

http://max.jsrhost.com/ajaxify/

however, the latest history.js file works in chrome:

http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin/#demos

I mainly noticed the old one used camelCase (historyInit()) and the new one does not (history.init())..

Can anyone better then me provide a easy fix, I tried it once, with no luck, but it seems so simple, I am sure with just a few mods to the ajaxify.js file, it should work fine..

I noticed the creator of that plugin seems to be registered here on stackoverflow, so hopefully he can help..his contact form doesnt appear to actually send on his website..

thanks!

Todd

Answer (score 1):

I realise this is an old question, but I would like to point out a plugin which does something similar.

http://www.swook.net/p/jquery-ajaxify-plugin.html

I created this plugin without knowledge about the existence of Max's outdated Ajaxify plugin.
I now realise that I should have checked the availability of the name before renaming my plugin (which was called dynload_link) but I will be keeping the name until I think of another one, especially since his plugin is outdated.

My Ajaxify plugin converts internal links and loads the contents of specified containers into the current loaded one. It has full HTML5 history support as well as URL anchor support.
It is quick and simple to use and I am willing to expand on its features if necessary.

Comment: I am trying to use your ajaxify plugin in my site, I am using this code: ` <script src="http://files.swook.net/js/jquery.ajaxify.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery.Ajaxify.all();
    </script>' but nothing happening. I changed `$` to `jQuery` for no conflict. please suggest